# How to sort a DateTime list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime

I fetch data from firebase and I want to sort the date data I receive by date. The object I receive look like the following:

Appointment Model

```
class MAppointment with ChangeNotifier {
  String id;
  String title;
  String location;
  DateTime createdAt;
  String email;
  List<Events> events;
  List<Participants> participants;
  String nameOriginater;

  MAppointment({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.location,
    this.createdAt,
    this.email,
    this.events,
    this.participants,
    this.nameOriginater,
  });

  MAppointment.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    id = data['id'];
    title = data['title'];
    location = data['location'];
    createdAt = data['created_at'];
    email = data['email'];
    events =
        List.from(data['events']).map((item) => Events.fromMap(item)).toList();
    participants = List.from(data['participants'])
        .map((item) => Participants.fromMap(item))
        .toList();
    nameOriginater = data['name'];
  }
}
```

Event Model

```
class Events with ChangeNotifier {
  DateTime end;
  String name;
  DateTime start;
  bool timed;

  Events(this.end, this.name, this.start, this.timed);

  Events.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> data) {
    end = data['end'];
    name = data['name'];
    start = data['start'];
    timed = data['timed'];
  }

  Map<dynamic, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {'end': end, 'name': name, 'start': start, 'timed': timed};
  }
}
```

I later get the MAppointment by the provider as **items** `(List<MAppointment> items)`.
How can I order the **event part** by date for items[0].events? The reference for the sort should be items[0].events[0].**start**

Comment: What actually do you want to sort? Whether sort items that come from firebase or sort items based on the date field from the firebase collection?

Comment: If you want to sort the events collection's start date from the items[0] index, you can get it by the framework sort method. Like, `items[0].events.sort((a,b) => a.compareTo(b));` for ascending. `items[0].events.sort((a,b) => b.compareTo(a));` for descending.

Comment: It shows me "The method 'sort' isn't defined for the type 'DateTime'" when I try your approach @AshokKuvaraja

Comment: You have to use the sort method in the List of DateTime items. Not DateTime single object. Can you please recheck your code or ping it here?